# SVG does not animate correctly on firefox but works fine in chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

So as the title says, I'm trying to animate an SVG using css animations. In chrome the `svg elements` smoothly transition from 0 opacity to 1 but in firefox it just pops straight to 1 opacity without any delay or transition, Sometimes if I refresh the page continuously then out of 10 it might work once. In the below code you'll see I have applied animations on specific svg elements using their `id` attributes, Can someone please point out what could be going wrong in here?

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

#circle9114 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 250ms forwards;
}

#circle9155 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 500ms forwards;
}

#circle9161 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 750ms forwards;
}

#circle9161-1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 100ms forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 217 161" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="g13358">
          <path
            id="path8997"
            d="M95.0557 113.098C101.309 113.098 106.379 108.029 106.379 101.775C106.379 95.522 101.309 90.4526 95.0557 90.4526C88.8023 90.4526 83.733 95.522 83.733 101.775C83.733 108.029 88.8023 113.098 95.0557 113.098Z"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9032"
            d="M105.901 101.775H140.795"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.10067"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9114"
            d="M149.711 109.66C154.276 109.66 157.977 105.959 157.977 101.394C157.977 96.8288 154.276 93.1279 149.711 93.1279C145.146 93.1279 141.445 96.8288 141.445 101.394C141.445 105.959 145.146 109.66 149.711 109.66Z"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9153"
            d="M98.779 112.469L193.787 144.58"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9155"
            d="M204.667 160.184C210.921 160.184 215.99 155.114 215.99 148.861C215.99 142.607 210.921 137.538 204.667 137.538C198.414 137.538 193.345 142.607 193.345 148.861C193.345 155.114 198.414 160.184 204.667 160.184Z"
            fill="#FFFF00"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9157"
            d="M21.8185 134.933L83.9439 103.951"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.10068"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9161"
            d="M12.3228 153.512C18.5762 153.512 23.6456 148.442 23.6456 142.189C23.6456 135.935 18.5762 130.866 12.3228 130.866C6.06935 130.866 1 135.935 1 142.189C1 148.442 6.06935 153.512 12.3228 153.512Z"
            fill="#008000"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9161-1"
            d="M72.7234 23.6456C78.9768 23.6456 84.0461 18.5762 84.0461 12.3228C84.0461 6.06938 78.9768 1 72.7234 1C66.47 1 61.4006 6.06938 61.4006 12.3228C61.4006 18.5762 66.47 23.6456 72.7234 23.6456Z"
            fill="#000080"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9163"
            d="M75.1572 24.1781L89.0043 92.2054"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.10067"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same results in both Firefox and Chrome. Could you please be a bit more explicit on what you see?

Comment: You have an "old" version of firefox, update that you willl see same result.

Comment: @Kaiido In chrome it smoothly transitions from 0 opacity to opacity 1, But in firefox it just pops from 0 to 1, If I refresh the page continuously then out of 10 times it might work correctly only once.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'm pretty sure I'm using the latest version, I've also checked for updates from the settings and it says "Up to date!"

Comment: ... Which version of Firefox, on which platform? Is this true also for the snippet in the question? (it's a small area, so some graphical bugs may not reproduce here). <s>For me it works fine every time</s> in Firefox 90.0.2 on macOs. In any way, bugzilla.mozilla.org/ would be the place to go, to report this bug so that it can be fixed. \[edit]: I can now reproduce...

Comment: I saw your bug (because 90% i don't use firefox) then browser auto update start and now work like chrome. -- edit, now don't work.... mmmh.. firefox 90.0.2

Comment: @Kaiido Yes it is true for the snippet as well and I'm also using Firefox 90.0.2 on Windows, But I also have a linux machine running kubuntu, It happens with its Firefox as well.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes! As I've mentioned in the question if I refresh it works as expected only 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: Sounds like this is a regression, in which case please use https://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/ to find a regression range and report that information in the bugzilla bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should report this bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org so that they can fix it.
For the time being, a quick fix is to update both `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity` instead of `opacity`:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
[id^=circle] {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
#circle9114 {
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 250ms forwards;
}

#circle9155 {
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 500ms forwards;
}

#circle9161 {
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 750ms forwards;
}

#circle9161-1 {
  animation: appear 1000ms ease-in 100ms forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  to {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 217 161" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="g13358">
          <path
            id="path8997"
            d="M95.0557 113.098C101.309 113.098 106.379 108.029 106.379 101.775C106.379 95.522 101.309 90.4526 95.0557 90.4526C88.8023 90.4526 83.733 95.522 83.733 101.775C83.733 108.029 88.8023 113.098 95.0557 113.098Z"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9032"
            d="M105.901 101.775H140.795"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.10067"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9114"
            d="M149.711 109.66C154.276 109.66 157.977 105.959 157.977 101.394C157.977 96.8288 154.276 93.1279 149.711 93.1279C145.146 93.1279 141.445 96.8288 141.445 101.394C141.445 105.959 145.146 109.66 149.711 109.66Z"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9153"
            d="M98.779 112.469L193.787 144.58"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9155"
            d="M204.667 160.184C210.921 160.184 215.99 155.114 215.99 148.861C215.99 142.607 210.921 137.538 204.667 137.538C198.414 137.538 193.345 142.607 193.345 148.861C193.345 155.114 198.414 160.184 204.667 160.184Z"
            fill="#FFFF00"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9157"
            d="M21.8185 134.933L83.9439 103.951"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.10068"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9161"
            d="M12.3228 153.512C18.5762 153.512 23.6456 148.442 23.6456 142.189C23.6456 135.935 18.5762 130.866 12.3228 130.866C6.06935 130.866 1 135.935 1 142.189C1 148.442 6.06935 153.512 12.3228 153.512Z"
            fill="#008000"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="circle9161-1"
            d="M72.7234 23.6456C78.9768 23.6456 84.0461 18.5762 84.0461 12.3228C84.0461 6.06938 78.9768 1 72.7234 1C66.47 1 61.4006 6.06938 61.4006 12.3228C61.4006 18.5762 66.47 23.6456 72.7234 23.6456Z"
            fill="#000080"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.32292"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
          <path
            id="path9163"
            d="M75.1572 24.1781L89.0043 92.2054"
            stroke="#1A1A1A"
            stroke-width="1.10067"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! I'll report this bug right away.

Comment: @ansme be sure to check first if it has been reported already. And please let us know the id of the issue so that we can track it too.